# Backbone views which don't know about their container, models to be fetched via AJAX, no UI/UX trade-offs and maintainable code

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

Since I'm not totally sure on which level my issue actually is to be solved best, I'd like to summarise the path I went and the things I tried first:

It's more or less about $el (I think).

As most basic backbone examples state, I started with having the $el defined within its view, like

```
Invoice.InvoiceView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#container'),
  template: ..,
  ..
});
```

It didn't feel right, that the view is supposed to know about its parent (=container). The paragraph 'Decouple Views from other DOM elements' written on `http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/backbone-js-lessons-learned-and-improved-sample-app/`) perfectly puts it into words.

Following this article's advice, I switched to passing $el over to the view while calling the `render()`-method. Example:

```
$('#container').html( new WineListView({model: app.wineList}).render().el );
```

So far so good - but now `render()` gets called, while it maybe shouldn't (yet).

For example the View asynchronously `fetch`es a model in its `initialize()`-routine. Adding a binding to `reset` or `sync` (e.g. like `this.model.bind('sync', this.render, this)`) makes sure, `render()` gets definitely called once the model is fetched, however above stated way, `render()` still might get called while the model isn't fetched *yet*.

Not nice, but working(TM), I solved that by checking for the model's existence of its primary key:

```
render: function() {
  if(this.model.get('id')) {
    ...
}
```

However, what I didn't expect - and if it really isn't documented (at least I didn't find anything about it) I think it really should be - the fetch operation doesn't seem to be atomic. While the primary key ('id') might be already part of the model, the rest might not, yet. So there's no guarantee the model is fetched completely that way. But that whole checking seemed wrong anyway, so I did some research and got pointed to the `deferred.done`-callback which sounded exactly what I was looking for, so my code morphed into this:

```
render: render() {
  var self = this;
  this.model.deferred.done(function() {
    self.model.get('..')
  };
  return this;
}
..
$('#container').html( new WineListView({model: app.wineList}).render().el);
```

It works! Nice, hu? Ehrm.. not really. It might be nice from the runtime-flow's point of view, but that code is quite cumbersome (to put it mildly..). But I'd even bite that bullet, if there wouldn't be that little, tiny detail, that this code sets (=replaces) the view **instantly**, but populates it later (due to the deferred).

Imagine you have two (full-page) views, a `show` and an `edit` one - and you'd like to instantly switch between the two (e.g. after hitting *save* in the *edit*-view it morphs into the *show*-view. But using above code it sets (=resets) the view immediately and **then** renders its content, once the `deferred` fires (as in, once fetching the model is completed).
This could be a short flickering or a long blank transition page. Either way, not cool.

So, I guess my question is: How to implement views, which don't know about their container, involve models which need to be fetched, views which should be rendered on demand (but only once the model is fetched **completely**), having no need to accept UI/UX trade-offs and - the cherry on the cake - having maintainable code in the end.

Comment: Shoudn't the view render when the fetch of the model completes?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the first method you found is terrible (*hard coding selector in view's constructor*)

The second: `new WineListView({model: app.wineList}).render().el` is very common and ok. This requires you to return the reference to view from render method, and everyone seems to follow this, which is unnecessary.

The best method (imo) is to simply attach the views element to the container, like this

```
$('#container').html(new WineListView({model: app.wineList}).el);
```

The `WineListView` doesn't need to know about where it's going to be used, and whatever is initializing `WineListView` doesn't need to worry about when to render the `WineListView` view instance:

because the `el` is a **live** reference to an HTML Element, the view instance can modify it anytime it wants to, and the changes will reflect wherever it is attached in DOM/ when it gets attached in DOM.

For example,

```
WineListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
     this.render(); // maybe call it here
     this.model.fetch({
       success: _.bind(this,function(){
         this.render(); // or maybe here 
       })
     });
  }
});
```

---

Regarding flickering: this hardly has to do anything with rendering or backbone, it's just that you're replacing one element with another and there will be an emptiness for a tiny bit of time even if your new view renders instantly. You should handle this using general techniques like transitions, loaders etc, or avoid having to switch elements (*For example convert labels into inputs in the same view, without switching view*)

Answer (score 0):

First off, the linked example is outdated. It's using version 0.9.2,
whereas the current version (2016-04-19) is 1.3.3. I recommend
you have look at the [change log](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog) and note the differences, there are many.

Using the `el` property is fine. Like everything though, there's a time and place.

`It didn't feel right, that the view is supposed to know about its parent (=container). The paragraph 'Decouple Views from other DOM elements' written on http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/backbone-js-lessons-learned-and-improved-sample-app/) perfectly puts it into words.`

I wouldn't define an `el` property on every view, but sometimes it makes sense, such as your example. Which is why, I'm assuming, Backbone allows the use of the `el` property. If you know `container` is already in the DOM, why not use it?

You have a few options:

1. The approach outlined in my original answer, a work-around.
2. fetch the model, and in the success callback, insert the view element into the DOM:

   ```
   model.fetch({
        success:function() {
            $('#container').html(new View({model:model}).render().el);
        }
   });
   ```

   Another work-around.
3. Define an `el` property on the view and fetch the model in the view `initialize` function. The new content will be rendered in the `container` element (also the view), when the content/model data is ready, by ready, I mean when the model has finished `fetch`ing from the server.

In short,

If you don't want to define an `el` property, go with number 1.

If you don't want to let the view fetch the model, go with number 2.

If you want to use the `el` property, go with number 3.

`So, I guess my question is: How to implement views, which don't know about their container`

In your example, I would use the `el` property, it's simple a solution with the least amount of code. Not using the `el` property here, turns into hacky work-arounds that involve more code (complexity) without adding any value (power).

Here's what the code looks like using `el`:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({url:'/model_url'});

var model = new Model();

// set-up a view
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'#container',
    template:'model_template',

    initialize:function() {
      this.model.fetch();
      this.listenTo(this.model,'sync',this.render);
    },

    render:function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
      return this;
    }
});

var view = new View({model:model});
```

Check out the documentation for [el](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el).

Here is an [updated working example](http://jsbin.com/wanijulatu/edit?html,js,output).

If there is an obvious flicker because, your model takes a noticeable amount of time
to be fetched from the server...maybe you should think about displaying a loading bar/variation thereof
while fetching the model. Otherwise instead of seeing the flicker, it will appear the
application is slow, delayed, or hanging..but in reality - it's waiting to render the next view,
waiting for the model to finish fetching from the server. Sitting on old content, just waiting for
the model to load new data to show new content.

Comment: What is the benefit of triggering a custom event, and then attaching the view after render over simply attaching the view after it's creation as mentioned in my answer?

Comment: *"This is where the flicker occurs."* -  no. the flicker occurs when one view is abruptly switched with another, when the view's el is already in DOM, the content arrival can be animated nicely, and really, single `append()` with entire view template is not going to create any performance impact in real world. Have you heard of AngularJS? It manipulate DOM close to real time in response to changes in modals, and more people use it  than Backbone. This is just additional code with no real world benefit in my opinion...

Comment: @TJ '''"This is where the flicker occurs." - no'' - yes. It is exactly the flickering I meant, in between replacing the current view with another one, while the view is not yet render'able (e.g. as the model isn't completely fetched yet). Although I'm not yet sure, that's the ultimate solution, it definitely reduces/elimininates my flicker problem.